# How could i get Bid adjustment actual % value from Adgroup -Device level - MOBILE from Google Adword API?

Tags: python, api, adgroup

How could i get Bid adjustment actual % value from Adgroup -Device level - MOBILE?

I have tried to use Python code from [Google Adword API Github](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/tree/master/examples).
Example folder: 'get_ad_group_bid_modifiers.py' to get bid value, whereas it returns bid in scale value between 1 to 10 instead of percentage.

It looks like this in API

[image]

Result

[image]

How to get Bid value in Adgroup level?